# If $\operatorname{ran}A$ is closed, is then $\operatorname{ran}A^2$ closed?

Tags: operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space or Hilbert space and $A : X\to X$ is bounded operator such that If $\operatorname{ran}A$ is closed. Is then also $\operatorname{ran}A^2$ closed?

I think not. Can anyone think of a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy example: Let $X=E\oplus E$ with $E$ an infinite-dimensional Banach space, $T\colon E\to E$ be compact but not finite-rank.  Then
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
T & 1_E\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\colon X\to X
$$
has $\operatorname{ran}A=E\oplus 0$ is closed, but $\operatorname{ran}A^2=\operatorname{ran}T\oplus 0$ is not closed.

Comment: Nice, thank you.